# Add a user to a usergroup on a remote server using Powershell DSC

Tags: powershell, remote-server, dsc, usergroups

I want to add a user to a particular usergroup on a remote server. Also, I need to check if the user is already in that group. Only if the user is not a part of that usergroup, add user. And I have to do all this using Powershell DSC(Desired State Configuration).

Comment: i would suggest that you look at a few examples here `https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/configurations` ....write your code...test...if something dosent work then you can post your code with the error and perhaps somebody can help.....

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to do this with a DSC configuration on the machine you are targeting, with the standard group resource.  A DSC configuration should try to describe the state of the local machine.

If you have a dependency on that user being created on another machine, it would be best to use [WaitForAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/crossnodedependencies) and have any resource that needs to wait on the remote resource depend on that resource.